# Renaming selected combobox item name?

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I am wondering if there if someone can share with a good sample of the combo box where possible to edit string of the text of the selected combobox item. I was not able to find any sample with this behavior enabled. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit the combobox items from the combobox control itself?

Comment: yes, edit the combobox string name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting IsEditable=True, like this:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="False">
    <ComboBoxItem>
       <TextBlock>select and change this text</TextBlock>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Is any way to have selected item. When, I apply isEditable property then IsSelected property does not active anymore. I applied SelectedIndex property and still does not show the item on build the app. Any ideas?

Comment: I fixed selected item issue. However, I have another question. I can edit the string but after selecting new item the edited string is lost. Is that possible to keep new string?

Comment: You should probably add IsReadOnly=False to combobox.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:
XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="cbo1" Margin="3">
            <ComboBoxItem>
                <TextBlock>First Item</TextBlock>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>
                <TextBlock>Second Item</TextBlock>
            </ComboBoxItem>            
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox Name="txtBox1" Margin="3" TextChanged="textBox1_textchanged"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
Private Sub textBox1_textchanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TextChangedEventArgs)

        If cbo1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            Dim i As ComboBoxItem = cbo1.SelectedItem
            i.Content.text = sender.text
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to convet it to C#, however, the code does not work. Getting error 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) My code is: private void textBox1_textchanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((cbo1.SelectedIndex > -1))
            {
                ComboBoxItem i = cbo1.SelectedItem;
                i.Content.text = sender.text;
            }
        }

Comment: This will work in C#: `public void textBox1_textchanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;

            if (cbo1.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                ComboBoxItem i = (ComboBoxItem)cbo1.SelectedItem;
                i.Content = t.Text;
            }
        }`